# Is str.replace() or combining two slices a better way to remove a character?

Tags: python

I am using CodingBat for practice exercises for the Python Language, I got to the "Warmup-1 > missing_char" exercise. The problem is as so:

> Given a non-empty string and an int n, return a new string where the
>   char at index n has been removed. The value of n will be a valid index
>   of a char in the original string (i.e. n will be in the range
>   0..len(str)-1 inclusive).

The examples were:

> missing_char('kitten', 1) → 'ktten'
>
> missing_char('kitten', 0) → 'itten'
>
> missing_char('kitten', 4) → 'kittn'

I wrote:

```
def missing_char(str, n):
  return str.replace(str[n], "")
```

It returned all correct. As I usually do when I get my answers correct, I look and see how CodingBat answered it. They answered it in the following way:

```
def missing_char(str, n):
  front = str[:n]   # up to but not including n
  back = str[n+1:]  # n+1 through end of string
  return front + back
```

Now, my question is the following: which answer is more viable? Is there setbacks to my method whereas CodingBat's method is more solid? Or is this just one of those "multiple approaches to things" kind of situation?

Comment: Did you try `missing_char('kitten', 2)`?

Comment: Your code is broken, if you try to replace, 3, or 4, it removes both 't' characters which is not the behavior you want.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth's comment indicates the drawback of your implementation -- it fails to handle that test case correctly.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth no, but "missing_char('code', 2)" was tested.

Comment: @WoodyPride I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of posting a formal answer and as all previous comments suggest:

`str.replace(char,"")`  will remove all occurences of the character regardless of their position.
`str[:n]+str[n+1:]` will only remove the n-th character.

So for that exercice  `str.replace(char,"")` is **not** suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to circumvent that problem by adding a count so that it only takes the first character:

```
def missing_char(str, n):
  return str.replace(str[n], "",1)
```

I added a 1 so that it only takes the first occurrence of that character